# If else function in R returning incorrect numbers and driving me crazy

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement

I imagine the solution is so simple here but I can't figure out what is wrong and need a new set of eyes.

I have a single column of data in a data frame I've named activity. It looks like this

```
    > head(activity,10)
           activity
    1   0.023624536
    2   0.024031221
    3   0.024266065
    4   0.024578568
    5   0.006467239
    6   0.007527727
    7  10.294613778
    8  11.820840273
    9  12.178685492
    10 12.188525138
```

I have this function which I want to iterate through my activity data and assign each a color based on activity value.

```
band_code <- function(x){
  x <- x[1]
  if(x < (-0.25)){color <- "A"}
  else if(x > (-0.25) && x < (0.25)){color <- "B"}
  else if(x > (0.25) && x < (0.75)){color <- "C"}
  else if(x > (0.75)){color <- "D"}
  return(color)
}
```

Then I use mutate to make a new column with the color data:

```
activity <- activity %>% mutate(Bands = band_code(activity))
```

and the result is a bunch of bands incorrectly coded B, where I should see B's and D's.

```
       activity Bands
1   0.023624536     B
2   0.024031221     B
3   0.024266065     B
4   0.024578568     B
5   0.006467239     B
6   0.007527727     B
7  10.294613778     B
8  11.820840273     B
9  12.178685492     B
10 12.188525138     B
```

I've played around with the way the cutoff values are entered in the function but I can't figure it out. Please, R angels out there, save me from what I know is am embarrassingly simple fix.

Comment: try including `rowwise()` before the `mutate()` line. Otherwise, if you include your data in a reprex, it'll be easier to help.

Comment: R is a vector-based language. Just do: `activity$Bands <- cut(activity$activity, c(-Inf, -0.25, 0.25, 0.75, Inf), LETTERS[1:4])`

Comment: @dash2 That should be the answer. Maybe rewritten as a function with chosen breaks and labels, to simplify the call to `band_code(activity)`.

Comment: try looking at `case_when` instead of writing your own function

Comment: Nooo... there's so much bad code out there like `mutate(y=case_when(x == 1 ~ 2, x == 2 ~ 4, ...))` instead of just `df$y <- 2* df$x`. `dplyr` is fine but at least be aware that there are functions in base R.

Comment: this worked!!!!!!!!! THANK YOU KINGS AND QUEENS
```activity <- activity %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(Bands = band_code(activity))```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normal if else only works with the first argument with `rowwise` this works, alternatively `cut` works vectorized:

```r
require(dplyr)
#> Loading required package: dplyr
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
band_code <- function(x){
  x <- x[1]
  if(x < (-0.25)){color <- "A"}
  else if(x > (-0.25) && x < (0.25)){color <- "B"}
  else if(x > (0.25) && x < (0.75)){color <- "C"}
  else if(x > (0.75)){color <- "D"}
  return(color)
}
data.frame(activity=c(.1,-1,.3,.6,.8)) %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(Bands = band_code(activity))
#> # A tibble: 5 × 2
#> # Rowwise: 
#>   activity Bands
#>      <dbl> <chr>
#> 1      0.1 B    
#> 2     -1   A    
#> 3      0.3 C    
#> 4      0.6 C    
#> 5      0.8 D
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Here are two functions that solve the problem, one base R `cut` in [dash2's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70763270/if-else-function-in-r-returning-incorrect-numbers-and-driving-me-crazy/70763449#comment125098671_70763270) and the other `dplyr::case_when`.

Note that none of the functions starts with `x <- x[1]`, a major error in your code. This only examines the first vector value, so all results correspond to that one.

```r
  library(dplyr)
  
  band_code <- function(x){
    cut(x, breaks = c(-Inf, -0.25, 0.25, 0.75, Inf), labels = c("A", "B", "C", "D"))
  }
  band_code2 <- function(x){
    case_when(
      x < -0.25 ~ "A",
      x > -0.25 & x < 0.25 ~ "B",
      x > 0.25 & x < 0.75 ~ "C",
      TRUE ~ "D"
    )
  }
  
  activity %>% 
    mutate(Bands = band_code(activity),
           Bands2 = band_code2(activity))
#>        activity Bands Bands2
#> 1   0.023624536     B      B
#> 2   0.024031221     B      B
#> 3   0.024266065     B      B
#> 4   0.024578568     B      B
#> 5   0.006467239     B      B
#> 6   0.007527727     B      B
#> 7  10.294613778     D      D
#> 8  11.820840273     D      D
#> 9  12.178685492     D      D
#> 10 12.188525138     D      D
```

---

## Data

```r
  activity <- read.table(text = "
       activity
    1   0.023624536
    2   0.024031221
    3   0.024266065
    4   0.024578568
    5   0.006467239
    6   0.007527727
    7  10.294613778
    8  11.820840273
    9  12.178685492
    10 12.188525138
", header = TRUE)
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>